# Azure DevOps yaml set input based on previous job result

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have been trying this for hours now, but without luck. In short what I am trying to accomplish:

1. I do some Bicep validation
2. Based on the result of the job (Succeeded or other), I want to notify to a Service Bus queue

I have this working with conditions, but then a lot of the code is duplicated which I want to avoid. Instead, I was planing to use one job to send the message, but with different input based on the result from the validation. Is this really impossible to implement in a neat way?

```
# Validate bicep template code
 - stage: "Validate"
   displayName: "Validate bicep code"
   jobs:
   # Validate Bicep code
    - job: "Validate_Bicep_Code"
      steps:
        - bash: 'az bicep build --file $(bicepPath)'
          displayName: 'Validate basic Bicep syntax'
          workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'

  # Send status to service bus
    - job: "Send_status_to_service_bus"
      dependsOn: "Validate_Bicep_Code"
      variables:
        validationResult: $[ dependencies.Validate_Bicep_Code.result ]
      condition: succeededOrFailed()
      steps:
      - template: templates/service-bus.yml
        parameters:
          ${{ if eq(variables.validationResult, 'Succeeded') }}:
            status: 'completed'
            message: 'Bicep code validation succeeded'
          ${{ if ne(variables.validationResult, 'Succeeded') }}:
            status: 'failed'
            message: 'Bicep code validation failed'
```

Answer (score 0):

I can use the following yaml to run the template based on the result from the validation step in one job.

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
stages:
 - stage: "Validate"
   displayName: "Validate bicep code"
   jobs:
   # Validate Bicep code
    - job: "Validate_Bicep_Code"
      steps:
      - task: Bash@3
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: 'az bicep build --file $(bicepPath)'
          workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        displayName: 'Validate basic Bicep syntax'

      #set variable ValidateStatus value when the first task is succeeded
      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: 'ValidateStatus succeeded'
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ValidateStatus]succeeded"      
        condition: succeeded()

      #set variable ValidateStatus value when the first task is failed
      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: 'ValidateStatus failed'
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ValidateStatus]failed"      
        condition: failed()
      
      - template: templates/service-bus.yml
        parameters:              
            status: '$(ValidateStatus)'
            message: 'Bicep code validation $(ValidateStatus)'
```

My test templates/service-bus.yml :

```
parameters:
- name: status
  type: string
- name: message
  type: string


steps:
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: service-bus task 
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
  inputs:
    script: |
      echo ${{ parameters.status}}
      echo ${{ parameters.message}}
```

Another way you can try is to use `if else` and set the variable in the first step. I didn't have a bicep file to build so I am not sure if it will return the right value in your case. So, it is just for your reference.

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
jobs:
- job: Validate_Bicep_Code
  steps:
    - bash: |
        if az bicep build --file $(bicepPath); then
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ValidateStatus]Succeeded"
        else
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ValidateStatus]Failed"
        fi
      displayName: 'Validate basic Bicep syntax'
      name: bicepValidation
    - template: templates/service-bus.yml
      parameters:              
          status: '$(ValidateStatus)'
          message: 'Bicep code validation $(ValidateStatus)'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **"${{ if eq(variables.validationResult, 'Succeeded') }}:"** is rendered at compile time
2. **"validationResult: $[ dependencies.Validate_Bicep_Code.result ]"** is rendered at runtime

compile time is the precursor of runtime, so  **"${{ if eq(variables.validationResult, 'Succeeded') }}:"** always be **"false"** because **variables.validationResult** has not been calculated out at complie time.

using condition instead, here is a sample:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - 'master'
  paths:
    include:
      - "azure-pipelines.yml"

stages:
# Validate bicep template code
 - stage: "Validate"
   displayName: "Validate bicep code"
   jobs:
   # Validate Bicep code
    - job: "Validate_Bicep_Code"
      steps:
        - bash: 'echo helloworld'
          displayName: 'Validate basic Bicep syntax'
          workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'

  # Send status to service bus
    - job: "Send_status_to_service_bus"
      dependsOn: "Validate_Bicep_Code"
      variables:
        validationResult: $[ dependencies.Validate_Bicep_Code.result ]
        validationResult1: 'Succeeded'
      condition: succeededOrFailed()
      steps:
      - script: |
          echo $(validationResult)
        displayName: debug the calculated variable

      - task: PowerShell@2
        condition: eq(variables.validationResult, 'Succeeded')
        inputs:
          targetType: inline
          script: |
            Write-Host "test message in states Succeeded"

      - task: PowerShell@2
        condition: eq(variables.validationResult, 'Failed')
        inputs:
          targetType: inline
          script: |
            Write-Host "test message  in states failed"
```